# git reset --merge y reset --keep

Tags: git

Tratando de profundizar mas en git me encontre con un par de opciones en git sin embargo tras leer la documentación e investigar por mi cuenta no logro comprender del todo como funcionan y que es exactamente lo que hacen los siguientes comandos

```
 git reset --merge <commit>
 git reset --keep <commit>
```

He hecho algunas pruebas basicas para ver si descubria como funcionan

para ello cree un nuevo repositorio con 3 commits

- El primero agrego un archivo (file1) con una sola linea.
- El segundo agrego una nueva linea al archivo
- El tercero agrego una nueva linea al archivo y creo un archivo nuevo (file2)

luego hago el **git reset --merge** sobre al primer commit y me resetea el working tree en vez de actualizarlo (como dice en la documentacion) es decir como si estuviera haciendo un **reset --hard**

el reset --keep hace lo mismo.

¿Alguien me podria explicar en que consisten y cual es el objetivo o caso practico para el cual fueron creados estos modos de reset?